# Nullpointerexcepcion en obtener el archivo de properties en un projecto java

Tags: java, properties

Tengo un proyecto java con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi clase que lee dichas propiedades

```
public class PropertyValues {
InputStream inputStream;
HashMap<String,String> mapResources;

public PropertyValues() throws IOException {
    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "config.properties";

        inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }

        mapResources.put("rname", prop.getProperty("rname"));
        mapResources.put("channel", prop.getProperty("channel"));
        mapResources.put("serverdb", prop.getProperty("serverdb"));
        mapResources.put("portdb", prop.getProperty("portdb"));
        mapResources.put("dbname", prop.getProperty("dbname"));
        mapResources.put("userdb", prop.getProperty("userdb"));
        mapResources.put("passdb", prop.getProperty("passdb"));
        mapResources.put("replicationname", prop.getProperty("replicationname"));
        mapResources.put("tables", prop.getProperty("tables"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

El source folder "Resources" yo lo creé y dentro mi config.properties, tal ahí no va, entonces dónde?
Me marca null pointer exception.

Alguna idea?

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En estos dos enlaces se hace referencia a tu mismo problema:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676250/different-ways-of-loading-a-file-as-an-inputstream

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource

Un saludo!